# Call function from php script doesn't work

Tags: php

I want to send email after an insert in database, so I defined a function sendm in a separate file sendemail.php:

```
<?php
function sendm($recipient, $subject, $messagetext)
{
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'mypassword';
$mail->SetFrom('myemail@gmail.com', 'me');
$mail->AddAddress($recipient);
$mail->Subject = $subject;

$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '';
$message .= $messagetext;
$message .= '<table rules="all" width="600px">';
$message .= '<br>';
$message .= '<b>please dont reply.</b></td></tr>';
$message .= "</table>";
$message .= "</body></html>";

// add message body
$mail->MsgHTML($message);

try {
    $mail->Send();
    echo "Mail send successfully";
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
}
```

I tested it and it works, but when called from insert script (insertion.php), data are inserted in database but no email is sent:

```
<?php
  include 'sendemail.php'; 
  header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  //connection au serveur
  $cnx = mysql_connect( "localhost", "root", "passwd" ) ;

  //sélection de la base de données:
  $db  = mysql_select_db( "mydb" ) ;

  //récupération des valeurs des champs:

  $name     = $_POST["name"] ;
  //email:
  $email = $_POST["email"] ;

  mysql_set_charset("utf8");

  $sql = "INSERT  INTO demande (name, email)
            VALUES ('$name', '$email') " ;

  $requete = mysql_query($sql, $cnx) or die( mysql_error() ) ;

  if($requete)
  {
    echo("insert ok") ;
    $to = 'recipient@gmail.com';    
    $subject = 'test';
    $message = 'test message.<br>';
    sendm($to, $subject, $message);
  }
  else
  {
    echo("insert KO") ;
  }
?>
```

Thank you

Comment: Also, you're vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: What happens if you put the function in the same file? Does it work? Try more debug lines. I personally use error_log() instead of echo() since it keeps everything nice and neat.

Comment: I tried putting function in the same file, but it didn't work. When I call function with arguments separately via command line it works.

Comment: have you tried require_once('sendemail.php'); instead of include?

Comment: you could also try removing your "header" command.

Comment: what is the value of [function_exists("sendm")](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) when called after your `include 'sendemail.php';` line?

Comment: function_exists("sendm") returns 1

Comment: What if you move the `require` to outside the function in sendemail.php?